# Creating Java Exceptions to do things more than just printing message

Tags: java, exception

I am reading Effective Java Exception article now

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effective-exceptions-092345.html

I find this paragraph in the third page of the article

> Do not forget your exceptions are complete Java types that can
>   accommodate specialized fields, methods, and even constructors that
>   can be shaped for your unique purposes. For example, the
>   InsufficientFundsException type thrown by the imaginary
>   CheckingAccount processCheck() method could include an
>   OverdraftProtection object that is able to transfer funds needed to
>   cover the shortfall from another account whose identity depends on how
>   the checking account is set up.

If I check online I find the custom exception code something like this

```
public class DivisorCannotbeZeroException extends RuntimeException {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DivisorCannotbeZeroException(){
        super();
        System.out.println("I am doing something more");
    }

    public DivisorCannotbeZeroException(String message){
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Even the print statement is not working in that code.  Can you please explain me, about how to add more functionality to the custom exception class specific to our requirement?

Comment: The print statement is not working how? How can it not work? What are you expecting it to do? NB the suggestion in the quotation seems like amazingly poor design to me.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Personally I'd ignore that article in its entirety: I avoid putting too much logic into exception handlers: exceptions are supposed to restore the program to a stable state as quickly as possible, not do things like "transfer funds" which is possibly the *last* thing I'd do in an exception handler. Madness indeed.

Comment: I tried to follow that explanation, and add more functionality.  To start with I have added a print statement.  Its not printing though (may be a bad code).  But my main point is I like to do add functionality to the DivisorCannotbeZeroException in my case.  Also why the quoted point is poor design?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Bathsheba Author of that article categorized those things as faults and InsufficientFundsException is a logical issue.  So I guess he suggested to add a work around right in the exception itself

Comment: Both @Bathsheba and I understood that, and we both disagree. It is terrible advice. I'm not in favour of this tendency for StackOverflow becoming a validation site for arbtitrary Internet junk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to construct an instance of that `Exception` (with the default constructor) for that constructor to be invoked (usually by `throw`ing it), like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    throw new DivisorCannotbeZeroException();
}
```

Output is

```
I am doing something more
Exception in thread "main" com.stackoverflow.Example
    at com.stackoverflow.Example.main(Example.java:18)
```

Comment: oops a bad coding indeed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**MyException.java (User-Defined)**

```
  package com.journaldev.exceptions;

  public class MyException extends Exception {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4664456874499611218L;

        private String errorCode="Unknown_Exception";

        public MyException(String message, String errorCode){
            super(message);
            this.errorCode=errorCode;
        }

        public String getErrorCode(){
            return this.errorCode;
        } 
    }
```

**CustomException Example**

```
    package com.journaldev.exceptions;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    public class CustomExceptionExample {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws MyException {
            try {
                processFile("file.txt");
            } catch (MyException e) {
                processErrorCodes(e);
            }      
        }

        private static void processErrorCodes(MyException e) throws MyException {
            switch(e.getErrorCode()){
            case "BAD_FILE_TYPE":
                System.out.println("Bad File Type, notify user");
                throw e;
            case "FILE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION":
                System.out.println("File Not Found, notify user");
                throw e;
            case "FILE_CLOSE_EXCEPTION":
                System.out.println("File Close failed, just log it.");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Unknown exception occured, lets log it for further debugging."+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private static void processFile(String file) throws MyException {      
            InputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                throw new MyException(e.getMessage(),"FILE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION");
            }finally{
                try {
                    if(fis !=null)fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new MyException(e.getMessage(),"FILE_CLOSE_EXCEPTION");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Exception can be done for any other class can inherit properties for a particular process